# WiFi option in Ubuntu 20.04 not appearing

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I recently installed it alongside Windows 10. However, after the installation, no WiFi option is available. WiFi is working fine on Windows partition tho.

My laptop is a Lenovo T15 Gen 2, with an Intel  Wi-Fi AX210.

I tried to install additional wifi drivers, but when I go to Update and Software app, it says 'no additional drivers available'. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*update*

Following your suggestion, if I run the command

```
lspci | egrep -i --color 'wifi|wlan|wireless'
```

I get no output. While if I simply run

```
lspci
```

I find the following entry

```
09:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev1a)
```

Not sure what that means.

*update2*

By typing the command `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` I get the following

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Askubuntu!
This is a poorly made question. You are lacking very big chunks of information for anyone to help you out. Can you edit your post to include you laptop model, maybe even wifi chipset you have, and if you have done any troubleshooting to see? Any extra information you may have, as we in here does not know your setup and challenges by so little information :)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: PNVM load: please see the duplicate. Post back if not solved.

Comment: @chili555 It works! Following your answer, I ran the command `sudo mv /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pnvm  /usr/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.bak` , then I rebooted and the WiFi was there. Thank you so much, sir. That was so kind of you!

Comment: Glad it’s working! Thank you for your kind words.