# Wifi is not working. Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 Kubuntu 21.10 HP Omen

Tags: networking, kubuntu, iwlwifi, 21.10

My Wi-Fi is not working on my Laptop HP Omen. Currently, I only have Kubuntu 21.10 installed on it. No Windows. My ethernet works fine. I need my Wi-Fi up and running for my class tonight. I would really appreciate your help.

These are the output I ran while doing some research:

```
❯ lshw -C network

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:64300000-64303fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Here is more information output:

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 16)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 (rev 1a)
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Here is more information:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl    
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'iwlwifi': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

Another output:

```
     sudo lshw -class network -short && nmcli device status 

H/W path           Device          Class          Description
=============================================================
/0/100/1d.5/0      eth0            network        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
/0/100/1d.6/0                      network        Wi-Fi 6 AX200
```

I tried these solutions below but still didnt work:

1. [Intel Wireless WiFi Link, Wireless-N, Advanced-N, Ultimate-N devices](https://wiki.debian.org/iwlwifi#Installation)
2. [Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html)
3. [How to load iwlwifi driver? [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/990363/how-to-load-iwlwifi-driver)
4. [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291)
5. [WiFi option in Ubuntu 20.04 not appearing [duplicate]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1368427/wifi-option-in-ubuntu-20-04-not-appearing?noredirect=1&lq=1)
6. [Intel AX200 Wi-Fi adapter not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1226036/intel-ax200-wi-fi-adapter-not-working)
7. [Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217719/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

****UPDATE******

Additional Outputs:

```
❯ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for krillavilla: 
[    3.365932] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol reg_query_regdb_wmm (err -2)
[    3.366815] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
[    3.366830] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)
[  107.834074] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol reg_query_regdb_wmm (err -2)
[  107.834877] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
[  107.834929] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)
[ 1312.426473] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol reg_query_regdb_wmm (err -2)
[ 1312.427456] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
[ 1312.427516] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)
[ 2263.790882] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol reg_query_regdb_wmm (err -2)
[ 2263.791110] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_channel_to_freq_khz (err -2)
[ 2263.791123] iwlwifi: Unknown symbol ieee80211_hdrlen (err -2)

    ~/Downloads ▓▒░                                                                                        ░▒▓ at 09:40:36 AM  
❯ sudo dkms status    

    ~/Downloads ▓▒░                                                                                        ░▒▓ at 09:40:42 AM  
❯
```

***UPDATE*****

```
❯ sudo dkms status
[sudo] password for krillavilla: 

❯
```

**UPDATE**

```
❯ sudo updatedb && locate cfg80211
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/rtl8812au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/rtl8812au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/rtl88x2bu/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/src/8814au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/src/8814au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/src/88x2bu-20210702/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/Downloads/src/88x2bu-20210702/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/home/krillavilla/rtl8812au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/rtl8812au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/home/krillavilla/src/8814au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/home/krillavilla/src/8814au/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/usr/src/8812au-5.6.4.2_35491.20191025/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28/include/net/cfg80211-wext.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-28/include/net/cfg80211.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-30/include/net/cfg80211-wext.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.13.0-30/include/net/cfg80211.h
/usr/src/rtl8814au-5.8.5.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/usr/src/rtl8814au-5.8.5.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.13.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.13.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.c
/usr/src/rtl88x2bu-5.8.7.1/os_dep/linux/ioctl_cfg80211.h


❯ uname -r
5.13.0-30-generic
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `sudo dkms status`

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the post

Comment: Press `Ctrl` + `c` and get out of the > prompt and back to ~$ and try again: `sudo dkms status` I suspect that you have an unneeded and conflicting driver installed that we need to identify and remove.

Comment: @chili555 updated the post

Comment: Now let's see: `sudo updatedb && locate cfg80211` also: `uname -r`

Comment: @chili555 i have updated it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134373/discussion-between-chili555-and-krillavilla).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our chat, after searching and failing to find conflicting wireless drivers to explain this:

```
iwlwifi: Unknown symbol reg_query_regdb_wmm (err -2)
```

We decided to reinstall the package that provides your wireless driver *iwlwifi*:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
```

We also found that the driver wasn’t loading and unloading properly and that iwlwifi.conf was missing. The file was written containing:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Next, you said that your built-in Intel hasn’t good signal strength where it’s needed at the coffee shop. We then installed a driver for your USB wireless dongle using these instructions:

[How should I go about getting a wireless connection for my desktop when I have no access to ethernet?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1309703/how-should-i-go-about-getting-a-wireless-connection-for-my-desktop-when-i-have-n)

We agreed to blacklist the driver *iwlwifi* for the internal device so that the USB driver wouldn’t interfere. In order to use the Intel, remove the USB and do:

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```